# How to recursively determine quotient in prolog with limited predicates?

Tags: recursion, prolog, integer-division

So I have been trying to determine a quotient of integers in prolog by only using build in predicates "is", "*", "+" and "-". It expects the quotient to be an integer so I don't need any decimals or rest.

I quickly came up with a solution but for some reason it just won't work as intended. It keeps giving me the same error and I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am new to prolog btw. and due to university I have to look into it.

Here is what I am trying:

```
div(0, 0, _).
div(1, Dividend, Dividend).

div(Quotient, Dividend, Divisor) :- 
    NewDividend is Dividend - Divisor,
    div(NewQuotient, NewDividend , Divisor),
    NewQuotient + 1 is Quotient.
```

I have basically tried anything from swapping stuff around to adding more predicates such as "div(Dividend, Dividend, 1).".

Here is what I shows when I type div(Y, 15, 3).

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [13] 0+1 is _2768
ERROR:   [12] div(_2798,3,3) at div.pl:63
ERROR:   [11] div(_2826,6,3) at div.pl:63
ERROR:   [10] div(_2854,9,3) at div.pl:63
ERROR:    [9] div(_2882,12,3) at div.pl:63
ERROR:    [8] div(_2910,15,3) at div.pl:63
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

I kinda understand what the errors want to tell me but I just don't get why it won't work as I expect it to work. It gets that the quotient is 0 if dividend is 0 and from there on it should just add 1s until it is back at the first call but it won't. I have to use this signature for my predicate by the way. It is an assignment from the university.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
div(0,0,_).

div(Quotient, Dividend, Divisor) :- 
    Rest is Dividend - Divisor,
    div(NewQuotient, Rest, Divisor),
    Quotient is NewQuotient + 1.
```